# How to upload file with non-ASCII filename using REST-service?

Tags: java, html, spring, rest, iframe

I create Java 7 REST service using Spring, Apache CXF.

`public SuccessfulResponse uploadFile(@Multipart("report") Attachment attachment)`

I use "Content-Disposition" parameter in order to retrieve file name. I've read some solutions which are usedfor downloading files (for example, url-encoding). But how to cope with non-ASCII filenames for upload? Is it a client-side or a server-side solution? The signature of the method above can be changed. The client side uses  html5 file api + iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience is that content-disposition doesn't handle UTF8 in general. You can simply add another multipart field for the filename - multipart fields support charset indication and handles UTF8 chars if done correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UTF8 for a filename (according to https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6266 and https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5987). For the Spring the easiest way is to use `org.springframework.http.ContentDisposition` class. For example:

```java
ContentDisposition disposition = ContentDisposition
    .builder("attachment")
    .filename("репорт.export", StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    .build();
return ResponseEntity
    .ok()
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, disposition.toString())
    .body((out) -> messageService.exportMessages(out));
```

It is an example to send the file from the server (download). To upload the file you can follow the same RFC, even the Content-Disposition header must be prepared on the browser, by JavaScript for example, and looks like:

```
Content-Disposition: attachment;
                      filename="EURO rates";
                      filename*=utf-8''%e2%82%ac%20rates
```

Parameter `filename` is optional in this case and is a fallback for the systems that don't support the RFC 6266 (it contains the ASCII file name). Value for `filename*` must the URL Encoded (https://www.url-encode-decode.com).